# Is this a callback function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arrow-functions

I m trying to write a callback function but not sure if i did it right.Can you check and correct ?

`

```
let username = prompt("Enter your username :");
let password = prompt("Enter your password :");
const userValid = /^[a-za-z0-9_.]*$/.test(username);
const passwordValid = /^[a-za-z0-9_]*$/.test(password);
  

let check = () => {
    if(userValid && passwordValid){
        correct();
    }else{
        not();
    }
}

let correct = () => {
    let msg = new Date(); 
    alert(`Welcome ${username}! Today is ${msg}.`);

}

let not = ()=> {
    alert(`Given username and password pair is not correct.Please try again!`);
}
check(correct,not)
```

`

Comment: A callback is generally passed to another function to be called later

Comment: A callback is always a function, but your functions are no callbacks since they're not passed via parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the functions in as parameters to `check`:

```
let check = (correct, not) => {
    if(userValid && passwordValid){
        correct();
    }else{
        not();
    }
};
```